# Position bottom right corner of Div center of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with a background image, I'm struggling to position it correctly to my requirements.

I want to position the div's bottom right corner to be center of the page, with the top left corner positioned top left and adjusting at different resolutions keeping in those positions.

I hope it makes sense.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: unfortunatly it doesnt make sence without JSfiddlE :)

Comment: `body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }` and `div { width: 50%; height: 50%; }` so far... any wishes with the background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let make your problem more simplify and then put the solution.

1. First thing you need to have a container or place that should be exactly in the center of the page.
2. Now you want another div that should be at the bottom-right of this centered div.

As we know 
*absolute positioned element starts computing its position from their last relatively positioned parent*.
So what you can do it create a centered div and inside that create container that will be relatively positioned and works as a parent of bottom-right div. now you can put you bottom-right div with absolute position inside it.

Here is sample of code.

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bottomRight">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
body{
   background:#EFEFEF;
}
.center {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -150px;
   margin-top: -150px;
   background:Red;
}

.container{
   position:relative;
   background:yellow;
   height:100%;
 }
.bottomRight{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:Blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
 }
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LtyCT/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to position an element such that its corners are in specific locations relative to the page, [you could just position it absolutely](http://jsfiddle.net/8eVSM/):

```
div {
    position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 50%;
      bottom: 50%;
      left: 0;
}
```

Essentially, this will specify the locations of its edges at all times, regardless of how the window is (re)sized.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly your question, i think you should add these css rules:

```
.your_div_class{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```